# Get form value from URL variable opencart admin login

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I'm trying to achieve this, When I pass a variable in admin url login page like this

admin/index.php?route=common/login?email=test@test.com

The url value "email" gets in the username input field

I'm using opencart 3 and I changed the login to be with email instead of user name

Comment: `?route=common/login?email=test@test.com` will be serverside in `$_GET['route']` with value `common/login?email=test@test.com`, you should change `?` to `&` in that part, which then `$_GET['email']` will be populated, which you can then add to `value=""` in the input (after checking email is valid etc)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks I got it now

Answer (score -1):

You can pass variables in the URL using the below format.

**base_url** or **domain**?**variable_1=value_1&variable_2=value_2.........&variable_n=value_n**
You can access the value of each variable
$_GET['variable_1'],$_GET['variable_2']....$_GET['variable_n'].
if you are using email input field in **form** tag method should be  GET[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF7hT.png)